# MS Access 2010 - Is it possible to embed multiple related subforms onto one master?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, one-to-many, subform, subforms

Context:

I have a master form with just four fields, that I would like to keep in dataview. I would like to embed three 1:M subforms onto this master form, all of which I want to stay in form view. When the user selects a row on the master form I want all three subforms navigate to the appropriate record. When the user wants to add a new record to the master form, I would like them to be able to click the '+' box on the master form, and have that open up or navigate to a blank new record on all three subforms that would belong to the new record in the master.

Right now I am able to link one subform in form view to the master form in dataview. But when I try to add multiple subforms, I am still only able to see one subform in Form View- the other two dont show up, even though all three show up in Design View. I know they are linked correctly, because it doesn't matter which of the three I test with, they all work on their own but not together.

How can I have all three embedded subforms work together in form view on a master form that uses data view?

OR

Am I going about this all wrong? Based on my roundabout explanation, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Are there data in your child forms? Are they setup to allow additions? (not essential for showing data but if they are not then it will look like the form didn't load when no data are present). Do you have anchoring setup such that it covers the other forms?

Comment: There is no data in the child forms, but I have a temporary field for displaying the foreign key that links it to the master form. When I create new data, it successfully links to the master form on the correct record. But, again, its only the one subform that I can do this with. I do have vertical and horizontal anchoring set to both, perhaps that is a problem? I thought that would just line each successive form up with whats around it but perhaps Im wrong?

Comment: I think they are being covered up. Is your design view a lot smaller than your actual form when it opens?

Comment: Design view actually seems to be the largest of the three views, mostly because the data view form shows up larger in design view than form view.

Comment: I can upload a couple of screenshots in about an hour if you think that would help. It seems like one of the stupid simple solutions that is taking forever to track down.

Comment: Ah one more thing, if I set all three subforms to datasheet view.. They all show up and are linked correctly. I'd rather have it be a single form view if possible, and that's when it limites the display to one form.